# Avoid over write the value each iteration Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a date picker. Which will show a list of dates. Suppose, current date is Oct 12, so it will show the next 365 days from current date in a scrollable list. I am using a for loop, but list of dates are not coming. It is over writing. For this, I think, I need to create a separate array. I will have to do it in simple Javascript, AngularJS but not jQuery. Please check my code below.

```js
function Ctrl($scope)
{   
    for (i=1; i<=365; i++){
    $scope.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{date | date:'MMM-dd'}}<br/> 
</div>
```

Comment: watchout, some years have 366 days

Comment: Yeah, but let's figure it out for 365 days. Once I get the concept, I can easily put any validation.

Comment: do you want `Jan-01, Jan-05, ..., July-15, ...., Dec-31`

Comment: I want Jan 01, Jan 02 .... Feb 01, Feb 03 ...Mar 01 Mar02 Mar 03..... Dec 31. Yes, current date to next 365 all dates. Suppose, current date is Oct 12, so I want all dates to next 365.

Comment: @cyberoy. is it? http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/dv9uowc2/

Comment: You just did it. Thank you very much. Please post it as an answer, so that I can approve. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is already working fine. Suppose, next year is leap year. So, it is taking 29 days in Feb. This one is working fine. Just, in this case, it is showing upto next year Oct 10 instead Oct 11. But, this is okay. I can negotiate it.

Comment: I find solution for one year (without static 365). Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fill an array with the dates and then render them using ng-repeat.

```
function Ctrl($scope){   
  $scope.dates = [];
  var date = new Date();
  for(var i = 1; i < 365; i += 1) {
    $scope.dates.push(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1););
  }
}



<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date | date:'MMM-dd'}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please test it here. :- http://jsfiddle.net/  I am getting only Oct12 Oct12 Oct12 and so on.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the date now increments by 1 day.

Comment: It is showing Oct 12 Oct 15 like that. All dates are not showing.

Comment: just replace from `+i` to `+1`. Then it will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another version to solve question:

**EDITED:**
However, `$scope.dates.push(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));` (**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/dv9uowc2/2/)**) is faster than my following codes (`setTime(...)`) (**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/dv9uowc2/)**)

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    var count = new Date();
    $scope.dates = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {

        $scope.dates.push(count);
        var next = new Date();
        next.setTime(count.getTime() + (1000 * 3600 * 24))
        count = next;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You can do it without static 365; **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/oaqpzb20/)**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    var day = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    end.setYear(2016)
    $scope.dates = [];
    while (end > day) {
        $scope.dates.push(day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1));
    }
}
```